# How to get File Navigator View in MacOS App

Tags: swift, macos, file

I have seen in many apps a simple tree navigator view, like this in Xcode:

[image]

I am creating my own IDE and would like to know if there is there a view for this?

Comment: You are looking for `NSOutlineView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@TheNextman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233944/thenextman) said, I need `NSOutlineView`, which was perfect. I followed this tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1201-nsoutlineview-on-macos-tutorial